# Adding a download to idm stopped

Tags: firefox, download, download-manager

I have a question regarding IDM (internet download manager).

I’m trying to download a large amount of files and having all the files run at the same time would not only slow down my computer but all my internet.

I was wondering if there was a way to add a download but not start it wait away and either start it after the current downloads are finished or wait until I manually start it.

Answer (score 0):

> IDM has such option, but it works only with Scheduler. You need to add
>   all downloads you need into IDM queue (press "Download Later" in
>   "Download File Info" dialog).
>
> Then open "Scheduler" IDM dialog, select "Files in the Queue" tab
>   and set "Download # files at the same time".
>
> If you have several queues you need to repeat this for each queue that
>   you have in "Queue" list (arrow 3 on the image). Then you should press
>   "Start queue" toolbar button in the main IDM dialog.
>
> IDM will download all files in the queue one by one but using only #
>   of downloads at the same time. Please note that this option does not
>   work for downloads that you start manually.

[Source](http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/register/new_faq/functions5.html)